# Having trouble with Php, Mysql and UTF8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Problem, simple and annoying.

---

Im just trying to print a list of names, collected from my mysql database.

The PHP-files are saved in utf8, the database and tables are set to use utf8. Still 'å,ä,ö', for example, outputs as �. Can't believe I'm still having this issue.

[image]

Of course, Latin1 solves the problem. The thing is that I have to use utf8 since I'm doing some json_encode for sending the data to an ajax-script.

[image]

Any idea what on earth could be wrong?

Should I convert the data to utf8 before returning it perhaps? Seems weird I should have to..

Comment: Posting pictures of the code forces others to retype all the code if they want to test it and hardly provides added value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`...

Try running `SET NAMES UTF8` query after you connect to database...

```
function connect($server, $database, $username, $password, $charset = "UTF8"){
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $database, $password);
    if(!$link){
        die("Unable to connect to database server.");
    }
    mysql_selectdb($database);
    if(function_exists("mysql_set_charset")){
        mysql_set_charset($charset, $link);
    }else{
        mysql_query("SET NAMES $charset");   
    }
}
```

Also make sure you have this (or via header()) in your HTML...

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Xavio, running query in phpMyAdmin returns properly encoded data? If so then it must be in connection... Try running `mysqli_set_charset($link , "UTF8")`... also check you table collation if it's UTF8... http://pokit.etf.ba/get/8ce9605f0dd798a232889822065286da.png... set to UNICODE not GENERAL and try again...

Comment: Yup, looks good in PhpMyAdmin. If i print_r before even returning from my function, it's looking weir.... OH. That litle snippet actually did it! Just put that in my sqlConnect()-function. Works fine now. Sorta strange that I need it though?.. Being that I've set like everything to utf8. But gonna check that Unicode/General out though.

Comment: It is not strange, it is the first thing you do after connecting to database, you need to set connection collation to UTF8 (connection between PHP and SQL database)... Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do...

1. Make sure your HTML header is sending the correct charset:

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
2. Use [`utf_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) when adding your names to the array. The line in your should be

   `$guests[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);`

Comment: And if I add the names directly in, let's say, PhpMyAdmin? That's a bad idea then?

Comment: @Jaitsu, bad idea to do this.

Comment: @Jaitsu, as I understood, data is already UTF8, and iconv is much better solution then utf8_encode.

Comment: `utf8_encode` as i understood it is useful for encoding data that is in a different character set, i.e. when the character set of the connection differs from the desired character set, looking at `iconv` does look like a better option