# Database charset/unicode (UTF-8) for Asian language

Tags: php, database, wordpress, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a problem on the setting of the language support in the PHP.

Where it use to be fine from my previous provider (shared-host)

And now I'm on my VPS with Godaddy.

The only problem that when from my Wordpress if I post language for example like Thai language in the post its ok but when I do some setting such as set the tagline

it will be a question mark like `??????????` and I went to the database and look and find the samething

so I look at the collation and it was set correctly at UFT-8 from where my previous provider have the same.

and I look at my php.ini it was with `iso-8859-1` then I changed it to `UFT-8` to see if that is actually help

but then still giving me the same result

is there anything other than this two to configure in order to get the language where it will be post in the database same as the language that I wanted to post in the db.???

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044030/having-trouble-with-php-mysql-and-utf8/6044073#6044073  You need to make sure that your db connection is set using UTF-8 and make sure your html meta tag sets utf-8 as charset

Comment: i checked is exactly the same file for the old one it just i moved to the new server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

Comment: ill try it out

there is another thing is only happen on saving the post on draft and when change setting  but when posting without save means just publish is all good

Comment: I accepting your answer but isn't really solve the problem as yet :(